# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree while installing @angular/material

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material

i'm having problems adding @angular/material to my project. Adding --legacy-peer-deps doesn't help. Adding --force pushes it through but after adding it to app.module.ts, html and running ng serve breaks it again giving even more confusing errors. Same happens if i try to install older version of @angular/material. Thank you for any help.
[image: Pic 1]

[image: Package.json]

This is what I get after installing @angular/material 11.2.12 with --peer-legacy-deps and running ng serve

[image: after]

Comment: Should version of @angular/material match @angular/cdk instead maybe?

Comment: Try adding using `ng add @angular/material@11`. Not telling ng add to use a specific version will install the latest version (13), and you are using 11.

Comment: I did simillar by running "npm i @angular/material@11.2.12". But then i get errors shown in last picture after running "ng serve"

Comment: Then do the same for @angular/cdk

Comment: facing the same issue with latest Ionic 6..